# Swift struct adopting protocol with static read-write property doesn't conform?

Tags: swift, protocols, static-members

Why doesn't this compile in Swift 1.2?

```
protocol Proto {
    static var name : String {get set}
}
struct Struct : Proto {
    static var name : String = "name"
}
```

(In Swift 1.1, just substitute `class` for `static` inside the protocol declaration. Same problem.)

The compiler complains that I'm not conforming to the protocol. But why am I not? It's easy to prove that the static property `name` in Struct *is* both readable and writable, so I've satisfied the spirit of the protocol, surely.

I have some additional observations:

- If I remove the `set` from the protocol requirement, the issue goes away.
- If I leave the `set` in place, but I remove the `static` (or `class`) from the protocol requirement and the `static` from the Struct implementation, the issue goes away.
- If I leave the `static` in place and turn the stored variable into a computed variable, the issue goes away.
- If I change the struct to a class, the issue goes away.

But I'm no closer to understanding what the compiler doesn't like about what I've got. Why doesn't a static stored property satisfy the protocol requirement?

Comment: This smells like a bug in the compiler to me. If you use a `class` instead of the `struct` it works on Swift 1.2

Comment: As in: `class Struct: Proto { static var name: String = "w00t" }`

Comment: Yes, I said that in the question (4th bullet item). Now tell me what I don't already know! :) - I find it hard to believe that it's a bug. If it were, it would be very old and I would expect it to have been fixed by now.

Comment: I vote compiler bug. Another bullet point for your list: even adding an empty `didSet` property observer fixes the issue.

Comment: With the `didSet` thing in there, too, this *really* smells like a bug. You've [filed it](http://bugreport.apple.com) already, right?

Comment: I wasn't going to file a bug on this but @NateCook definitely convinced me. This is, amazingly, a bug that has always been there and no one has noticed. I can't believe something so obvious has been missed all this time, but there it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point I'm persuaded by Nate Cook's example that this is nothing but a bug in the Swift compiler. As he points out, merely adding an empty `didSet` observer on the static variable allows the code to compile. The fact that this could make a difference, even though it makes no *functional* difference, has "bug" written all over it.

Answer (score 4):

The mothership fixeth in 6.3 (6D543q):

```
protocol Proto {
    static var name : String {get set}
}

struct Struct : Proto {
    static var name : String = "name"
}

Struct.name = "Frodo"

println(Struct.name)
```

now works:

```
-> "Frodo"
```

(tested in Playgrounds)
It really does seem like static was treated as a let / const variable, but your case now works in 6.3 Beta 3.  I'm just happy that lldb symbols are unbroken.