# didSet in Swift has a weird knock-on effect on mutating func

Tags: ios, swift

I just learned that mutating func is just a curried func with first parameter as inout, so the code below will work and change `firstName` to `"John"`

```
struct Person {
    var firstName = "Matt"

    mutating func changeName(fn: String) {
        firstName = fn
    }
}
var p = Person() 
let changer = Person.changeName
changer(&p)("John")
p.firstName
```

but the odd thing happend when I add property observer to `p` like below, you can see `firstName` is still "Matt", why?
[image]

Comment: "mutating func is just a curried func with first parameter as inout" Well, it's more general than that. What you want to say is that an instance method is a curried class method with the instance as the first parameter. The "mutating" business is just a special case of that.

Comment: @matt , I read your book, yes, I read that from your book

Comment: You found a great bug here. Very well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the newest accepted proposal [0042-flatten-method-type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0042-flatten-method-types.md), `self` is no more passed as curried function, so this problem is solved in the Swift 3

Answer (score 5):

An interesting note to take ist that the observer is called **before the curried setter is called**:

```
struct Person {
    var firstName = "Matt"

    mutating func changeName(fn: String) {
        firstName = fn
    }
}

var p: Person = Person() {
    didSet {
        print("p was set")
    }
}

print("1: \(p.firstName)")
let changer = Person.changeName
print("2: \(p.firstName)")
let setter = changer(&p)
print("3: \(p.firstName)")
setter("John")
print("4: \(p.firstName)")
p.changeName("John")
print("5: \(p.firstName)")
```

This prints:

```
1: Matt
2: Matt
p was set
3: Matt
4: Matt
p was set
5: John
```

So it seems that acquiring the setter method on the inout struct performs the actual mutation. This is explained by how `inout` parameters work semantically: When the parameter is passed to the function its value is copied to a place where the function can mutate it. When the function returns, the value is copied back to the original place, triggering setter observers once, whether the value did change or not.

When we change the way to get the pre-filled curried setter to:

```
let setter = p.changeName
```

... the compiler objects:

```
error: partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed
```

It seems that the compiler understands that closing over an inout value is a bad idea, as it is basically taking a reference on a value type.

The closure would let you change the value of the struct at any time, even when the compiler assumes it to be constant. To prevent this unfortunate situation, the compiler simply forbids closing over the inout.

You found a case which fools the compiler and works around the diagnostic. This seems to be an error and it should be filed.

**Short version:**

```
struct Foo {
    mutating func foo() {}
}

var f = Foo()
let m = Foo.foo
let s = m(&f)
```

One of the last two lines should emit an error, similar to `let x = f.foo`.

Comment: @matt I just wanted to call the mutating `addRedFunnel` on your `Person`, but then you deleted your post :(

Comment: I didn't want you to add it! :) — Very nice analysis. May I suggest you file the bug report, as the OP would probably find this daunting? And congrats to the OP on finding a nice bug. This is not the first time I've seen the addition of a setter observer change behavior in surprising ways, by the way.

Comment: @matt I wanted to give the OP some time to file it since I didn't discover it myself. I'll make sure it gets filed in the end, though.

Comment: Here is a q. of mine where behavior was changed by adding an (empty) setter observer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597490/swift-struct-adopting-protocol-with-static-read-write-property-doesnt-conform That bug is now fixed, but it is an example suggesting how setter observers must be messing with internals. I guess if I were really patient I could read the Swift source and learn how setter observers actually work, but I don't feel up to it...

Comment: In some cases the `inout` parameter passing is optimized to passing an actual memory address, without copying the values. This *might* explain why the "strange" behavior  does not occur without a property observer.

Comment: @MartinR Also, when the compiler sees all code, inlining might eliminate *any* calls. This could be prohibited when observers are in place, explaining the differing behavior from above.

Comment: @matt I just asked this to Joe Groff(@ jckarter), and here is his reply "inout semantics don't allow for partial application. We ought to reject the unapplied reference to Person.changeName", which I didn't fully understand

Comment: Fascinating. When you write `changer(p)("John")` it actually _invites_ you to use `&`. But here you're saying that maybe `let changer = Person.changeName` should never have been permitted, which I don't understand either, because it would be just fine if this weren't a mutating func.

Comment: Sounds like Joe identifies the problem to be the possibility to create a function value (or, what's the proper name for an unapplied closure?) with an `inout` parameter. This would, in turn, let you create a closure (reference type) that holds a reference to that temporary `inout` value.

Comment: @matt looks like there will no more answer, I just filed the problem to bugreport.apple.com, that is no daunting :) the ID is 24786063